# jQuery slider going over 100% and issue with disabling empty input

Tags: jquery

please see full working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfZgN/1/

```
//enable submit button
if (total == 100){
  if ($("input:text").is(":empty")) {
    $("input:text").attr('disabled','disabled'); 
  } else {
    $("input:text").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  $('.btn').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
  $('.btn').attr('disabled','disabled');  
  $("input:text").removeAttr('disabled');     
}
```

I am having 2 problems with the jQuery:

1. When it hits 100% it disables all inputs and i just want it to disable the empty ones, as they need to be able change and if they change and goes under 100 the other inputs become active again.
2. If you enter a bunch of numbers that goes over 100% it allows you to do this and shows for example 120% i need it to stop at 100%

Really helpful if someone could help me out here, its the last task :)

Thanks

Comment: Problem #1 is easy to remedy but how do you want to handle problem #2? If the user types a value that puts the total over 100% what should happen to the text they enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a test for when the total is greater than 100. In the example below, I set the value to 0 if the total will exceed 100, though you can put your own logic in instead.

If the value is equal to 100, then iterate through the inputs and disable those that don't have a value.

See this [updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfZgN/6/) with a working example.

```
if (total == 100){
    $("input:text").each(function(index) {
        var input = $(this);
        input.prop('disabled', input.val().length === 0);
    });
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    if(total > 100) {
        total = total - thisVal;
        $(this).val(0);
        alert('Total must be less than 100');
        //other logic here
    }
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);  
    $("input:text").prop('disabled', false);     
}
```

As an aside, it's generally recommended to use `prop()` when working with boolean properties like disabled, though it's not required.

Comment: Works on the % so doe snot go over but still seems to disable the inputs that have values? thanks for your help btw

Comment: Just saw your comment, any ideas on how i can resolve the disabled issue?

Comment: I updated my answer to include disabling the inputs when value === 100. Thanks for the catch @j08691